# ImageMagick: convert image to PDF with A4 page size and image fit to page

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert different image formats (bmp,jpg,gif,png,tiff-incluging multipaged) into a PDF format with A4 page size and with images fit to page (resized if necessary). Image should be positioned at the center of the page and I'd like to define an offset. 
I tried the code below but there is no offset at the top and the image quality is really poor.

```
convert png.png -gravity North -resize 500x500 -quality 100 -page a4x5x5 myout.pdf
```

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Mariusz

Comment: ImageMagick does not have a page size of a4x5x5. Use -resize 595 x 842 ... -extent 595 x 842

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the [ImageMagick support forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25693) I was able to find a solution:

```bash
convert image.tif -resize 575x823^> -gravity center -background white -extent 595x842 image.pdf
```

If you get an error try:

```
convert image.tif -resize 595x842^\> -gravity center -background white -extent 595x842 image.pdf
```

Comment: You could probably escape the > like that: -resize 575x823^\>

Comment: A google search took me here because the title of this thread is quite general. For simple uses, option `-page a4` does already a good job automatically: `convert file-pattern*.jpg -page a4 output.pdf`

Comment: If the image is smaller, and you want to resize it, use `-page 'A4<'`.

Answer (score 74):

If you want to keep the original resolution (lossless) you can try the following command:

```
convert png.png -background white -page a4 myoutput.pdf
```

Based on a comment posted before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573341/6747994

@m4tx This command only makes sense if the picture has a resolution above 500x800px, it does not zoom in, to avoid pixelated thumbnails.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again today and now it appears to work. I don't know what went wrong, I even used the exact same command from the shell history. Unfortunately I can't retract the downvote, as it is locked in now.

Comment: It seems it actually does not upscale small images to fit the whole page.

Comment: You need to specify the `-density` to avoid any issue when printing with "real size". https://stackoverflow.com/a/55125655/376454

Comment: using this I got images as landscapes not portraits as it was in original

Comment: @Wok Using `-density 72` I get an image which is smaller than an A4 page. If I remove it, then it has the right size, i.e. the same as an A4 page.

Answer (score 24):

You can convert to pdf using ImageMagick

```
convert png.png myout.pdf
```

but use pdfjam instead of ImageMagick to adjust the page size

```
pdfjam --paper a4paper --outfile myoutA4.pdf myout.pdf
```

pdfjam offers other options, which may fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution which works for me. 
When converting color tiff file to pdf, i have to use pdfjam to fix the image size to A4 page size.

Answer (score 21):

Found this somewhere on stackoverflow:

```sh
convert *.jpg -resize 1240x1753 \
                      -extent 1240x1753 -gravity center \
                      -units PixelsPerInch -density 150x150 multipage.pdf
```

Comment: -gravity should come before -extent

Comment: @fmw42 It doesn't matter.

Comment: It might not in Imagemagick 6, but it would in Imagemagick 7. Correct syntax is as I mentioned, but Imagemagick 6 is rather forgiving. Imagemagick 7 is more strictly adhering to correct syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would modify the images themselves (to add some white pixels around them). What I want is to add the images (resized or not) within an A4 page in a PDF, without the need to enlarge some images with white.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the density:

```
convert -density 80 -page a4 input_A.jpg input_B.jpg output.pdf
```

Otherwise, there can be an issue when printing with "actual size" instead of "fit". I have used a public printer where I could not choose "fit" and had to choose "actual size", in which case the printed page was only a part of the page which I wanted to print.

[image: Fit vs. Actual Size]

Comment: If you define -page a4 it shrinks the image to fit into a A4-PDF. If you print this with original size, than the paper is A4, independent on density. If you want to print it on a different size, you should neither use fit nor should use -density, you should change -page .... .

Comment: No. If you don't specify the density, and even if you specify page A4, the relevant part of the page won't necessarily be A4, it could be a tiny rectangle in the middle of the A4 page. Try to print with "actual size" instead of "fit", and you will see for yourself. I know, I have done it, and I was not messing with formats other than A4. Take a pic with a camera, and convert it to PDF.

Comment: I think the issue is that JoKalliauer speaks only about the page format (which is indeed an A4 paper), and I speak about the content in the page (which means that I want the content of the picture to fill the A4 paper as expected).