# Howto convert A4 jpeg scanned page to A4 pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick-convert

I have a jpeg scanned page (`toto.jpg`) that I want to convert to a A4 pdf file with imagemagick convert command.

I've been trying the `-page A4`, `-resize 595x842` and `-define pdf:fit-page=A4` options but it does not work, I don't obtain the correct size :

```bash
$ identify toto.jpg 
toto.jpg JPEG 1644x2304 1644x2304+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 902KB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ convert -density 300 -page a4 toto.jpg toto.pdf 
$ identify toto.pdf 
toto.pdf PDF 143x202 143x202+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 3.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ convert -density 300 -resize 595x842 toto.jpg toto.pdf 
$ identify toto.pdf 
toto.pdf PDF 143x200 143x200+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 3.66KB 0.000u 0:00.000
$ convert -density 300 -define pdf:fit-page=A4 toto.jpg toto.pdf 
$ identify toto.pdf 
toto.pdf PDF 395x553 395x553+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 27.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of trying, I've found the output resolution I was using was wrong.

To produce a pdf from a picture, one must change the output density to fit the screen's, that is to say 72dpi :

```bash
$ convert -density 72 -page A4 toto.jpg toto.pdf
```

this also works :

```bash
$ convert +density -page A4 toto.jpg toto.pdf
```

and the produced pdf is :

```bash
$ identify toto.pdf 
toto.pdf PDF 595x842 595x842+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 63.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: In my experience, the right density is closer to 80 dpi.

Comment: @Wok Actually, I don't even remember why I chose `72 dpi` because `xdpyinfo | grep dots` reports `96x96 dots per inch` for my screen but if I calculate it from the dimensions and resolution given by `xrandr | grep -w connected`, I find : `106.387 dpi x 106.326 dpi`

Comment: @Wok Do you have some documentation that would help understand which DPI resolution to choose ?

Comment: But that does change the resolution of the embedded jpg (reduced quality)?

Comment: @SebMa I chose 80 dpi by trial-and-error: 1) change dpi, 2) check the rendered page when trying to print it with the "Actual Size" setting. 3) If the dpi is too low, the rendered page does not fit in the printed page. If the dpi is too high, the rendered page is very tiny in the middle of the printed page.

Comment: @JoKalliauer I don't think so. See: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density "The -density option sets an attribute and does not alter the underlying raster image"